# How to make TextView responsive on devices with higher screen ratio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a very simple coupon application for Android, but I'm struggling with a TextView.

For devices with 16:9 screens, the TextView displays just OK, but the problem starts with devices such as Samsung Note 9 I have, which has 18:9 screen. TextView isn't getting bigger to fill the blank space.

For 16:9 screen I use a Google Pixel 2 emulator whereas for 18:9 screen I use my own Samsung Note 9.

Does anybody have any clues how to make my TextView responsive, so it can occupy the blank space?

Photos for my devices:

Pixel 2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUbJh.png
Samsung Note 9 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zg0u.jpg

I tried to play with AutoSizing TextView, but I have no clue how to make it work for my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.GeneratedCouponActivity" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="16dp">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                    android:text="DATA WYDANIA:"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="25/06/2019"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
            <TextView
                    android:text="UNIKALNY KOD:"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="f-62-pT-6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/coupon_icecream" android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/generated_coupon_rules"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView8" app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    />
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="bottom">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="95dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFC300"/>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="95dp" app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFC300"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use autosizing text view in that case. Try it on 720p (16:9) device, it may render text too small to read. You should also respect user fonts size settings, so on Pixel 2 with large fonts set text might be ineligible (since it becomes down scaled when user needs large font). As simple as it sounds you should have fixed font size (based on `sp`) and make that `TextView` scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `android:layout_height="140dp"` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

If you want to create one layout to support all screen sizes you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

**Here is an example using ConstraintLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view    I am some long text view     "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Date"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#ff1"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#ff1"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="560dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is how it will look (I am attaching an image from the layout editor so you could see the constraints and guidelines):**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `auto-sizing TextView` with these attributes in your `TextView`.

```
<TextView
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />
```

> Note: It is advised to not use a layout_width or layout_height of
>   "wrap_content" when using TextView auto-sizing, as this may lead to
>   unexpected results. Using a fixed dimension or "match_parent" is fine
>   (or a “0dp” match_constraint if you are using ConstraintLayout).

Read [Making the most of TextView auto-sizing on Android](https://medium.com/over-engineering/making-the-most-of-textview-auto-sizing-on-android-a39f71b6f3af) to have a deeper understanding of this.

Comment: You got my upvote for devoting your time with your answer. "Using a fixed dimension is fine " is not something that I fond of and let me explain: @szakes1 wants to make his layout responsive to all screen sizes, with fixed sizes on his views he will have to build a layout for every screen size. And that why I recommended him to use ConstraintLayout in my answer below. I just wanted to give you another option when developing your layouts.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Right bro. But I just gave a hint to get the gist of the answer. Keeping in mind that OP can figure out which layout fits best for his current need. Thanks for the upvote.