# android studio responsive textView,ImageView and Text

Tags: android, xml, firebase, textview, imageview

I have ImageView and TextViews in my game. I put TextView in ImageView and translate text to all languages. I ran into a problem. TextViews overflow from ImageViews, how can I make it suitable for all devices and all languages

**activity_mail.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nasilOynanir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nasil"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baslaImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNasil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/nasil"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/nasilOynanir"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/nasilOynanir"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nasilOynanir"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nasilOynanir"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433" />
```

strings.xml

```
Turkish
<string name="nasil">Nasıl Oynanır</string>

English
<string name="nasil">How to play</string>

Arabic
<string name="nasil">كيف ألعب</string>
```

**Different language screenshots**

[image]
[image]
[image]

1-First I tried reducing textview size but it creates incompatibility in different languages.
2-app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" I tried this but it didn't work

3-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029641/how-to-make-textview-responsive-on-devices-with-higher-screen-ratio i tried this but i couldn't

Comment: use that library(https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for the dynamic size of the image and text view or other components.
Now use that library(https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for the dynamic text size in your app

NOTE: Make the text length static, use auto resize of text in textview

Comment: can you show? @Ammar

Comment: Can you please explain, how is this question related to Firebase?